# What is the difference between add damage counters and attack damage

Tags: pokemon

On Dusclops(Flashfire 39/106), on the moved cursed drop it says that i can put 4 damage counters on my opponent's pokemon in any way I like. What is the difference from saying this as in do 40 damage to your opponents pokemon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Damage:

- Is affected by Weakness and Resistance, unless specified otherwise
- Is affected by effects like "Whenever an attack does damage"
- Can be prevented by "prevent all damage"
- Can be reduced by "any damage done to this Pokémon by attacks is reduced by XX", "divide that damage in half", etc.

Damage counters:

- Is prevented by "prevents all effects...", since placing damage counters is an effect of an attack.
- And you can pretty much revert everything that applies to normal damage.

Comment: And to illustrate, here's a practical example of when it matters: [Pyukumuku](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pyukumuku_(Sun_%26_Moon_47)) retaliates with 6 damage when it's knocked out by **damage** from an attack. You can avoid this by putting damage counters on Pyukumuku directly instead of dealing attack damage. Similarly, Exp. Share and Wish Baton only work when damaged by an attack, so you can prevent them happening with direct damage.

Answer (score 0):

"Doing damage" may be prevented by e.g. abilities or trainer cards, or otherwise trigger conditions in them.

Placing damage counters will not be prevented this way, or trigger the same conditions.